# Is it safe to plug guitar processor output directly into laptops's 3.5 mm slot?

Tags: electric-guitar

I sometimes record my guitar using Audacity, I use a 3.5 mm converter and connect my guitar cable directly into my laptop.

But I was wondering if I can do the same with my vox stomplab IIG processor to get effects like high gain distortion and all.

I heard somewhere that you shouldn't connect stompboxes output directly as it may damage laptop's inbuilt sound card.. but is it same case with guitar processors too?

Answer (score 1):

Connecting `guitar -> sound card` directly isn't much different than connecting `guitar -> pedal -> sound card`. It won't hurt your sound card. But it probably doesn't sound very good either, does it? You're missing both an amp and speaker which are essential to how an electric guitar sounds.

Your Vox modeling pedal will sound much better because it includes amp/speaker emulation and probably has a line-level output. Look for an "output" setting on the Vox and make sure it's set to "line" or something similar and you should be good to go.

Then if you later get into layering tracks like recording 2 guitar parts or playing over a drum track, you'll probably want something like [ASIO4ALL](http://www.asio4all.de/) to deal with the latency of a stock sound card.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the output your guitar processor gives you. They **should** all be in the same voltage range. But connecting a guitar or stomp box directly to the laptop will never give you a good sound. You should always use a sound card or audio interface. These are designed for the job, have the correct impedance and can cope with a wide range of voltages, gain, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your laptop is probably expecting a line level input. Your guitar is not a line level output, so you'll need something in between, either a preamp or your Vox processor. Otherwise, your guitar signal will be very quiet.

You shouldn't have any problems connecting your processor. When connecting the processor, set the volume output on the processor low and raise it gradually until the levels look good on the laptop (I usually shoot for -18dBFS). Since the processor's output is a headphone output, it will be higher than line level. You'll need to compensate for this or even a clean tone will sound distorted on the laptop.

What you really should get is a USB audio interface. They are not expensive (